# SQLite composite key (2 foreign keys) Link table

Tags: sqlite, database-design, create-table

I've read the rather cool styled *BNF grammar* for the SQLite create table statement

found here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

I was wondering how I'd go about creating a link table between these

I have one table, lets say, houses, and another electrical_items.

I want to create a link table to have the house_id and the item_id as a composite key, but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing it, it doesn't appear to allow a primary key to be a foreign key ?

N.B I want a third field pap_tested which stores the date the electrical item in the house was pap_tested so this linking table via composite primary key seems the best approach.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Either of these should work for your association table:

```
create table house_items (
    house_id integer not null,
    item_id  integer not null,
    foreign key (house_id) references houses(id),
    foreign key (item_id) references electrical_items(id),
    primary key (house_id, item_id)
)

create table house_items (
    house_id integer not null references houses(id),
    item_id  integer not null references electrical_items(id),
    primary key (house_id, item_id)
)
```

You'll probably want [separate (single column) indexes on `house_items.house_id` and `house_items.item_id`](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) as well.

Comment: Having followed the link I don't think it applies as house_id is a primary key of house and item_id of items.

Comment: Hi, in Android Studio SQLite3, the primary key is (_id) "Columns.ID" do i still use (id) or do i change it to (_id)?

Comment: @Ken you'd use `_id` in that case, the syntax is `foreign key (from_column_list) references to_table(to_column_list)`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement the first answer, it's a good practice to add a name to constraints, like the code below:

```
create table house_items (
    house_id integer not null,
    item_id  integer not null,
    constraint house_items_pk primary key (house_id, item_id),
    constraint house_items_house_fk foreign key (house_id) references houses(id),
    constraint house_items_items_fk foreign key (item_id) references electrical_items(id));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no prohibition about a PRIMARY KEY not also being a FOREIGN KEY for those designs that require this kind of relation.  Your problem isn't one of those, however, since the natural PRIMARY KEY in the linking table is a composite of the two columns, each a FOREIGN KEY back to one of the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I create a table with two foreign keys and options of on update cascade and on delete cascade.

```
CREATE TABLE category_subcategory
(
 category_subcategory_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 category_id             INTEGER NOT NULL,
 subcategory_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
 UPDATE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(subcategory_id) REFERENCES subcategories(subcategory_id) ON
 DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 );
```